# What are dark matter and dark energy?

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy

I've recently read about dark matter and dark energy. But unfortunately, there were not enough answers for me. The article I read was more of a hypothesis than a real answer. So I'm asking for all the information that you have and all the things you know about dark matter and dark energy. For example:

- What is it?
- Why does it exist?
- Where is it?
- From what does it form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read an article that presents a hypothesis on dark matter and dark energy, that is about as much as you will find right now. No one on this planet *knows* what they are. We only know from the behavior we see in the cosmos that there must be something we cannot detect out there influencing the movement of the heavens.

If you read and understand everything that has currently been written by an authority on the subject right now (January 2015), you will still not know the answers to the questions you have posed. If you truly must know, I suggest you begin by applying to enter into a PhD program in cosmology or astronomy.

Comment: @mark bailey If you want opinion, I think dark matter is made of a type of a particle or family of particles that are too massive to have been found by our largest colliders YET and only interact with other particles by way of gravity. I think dark energy (totally unrelated) is an "outward force" caused by a pressure from energy that is evenly distributed throughout all of space. See You Tube: Leonard Susskind: Cosmology Lecture 5 (Feb, 11, 2013). The math wasn't all that horrible.